# Big Sur Audio keeps switching to HDP codec from AADP when input and output is being used at same time

Tags: macbook-pro, audio

Title: Whenever I'm say, listening to music and talking to my friends over a voice chat platform, I'm noticing sound quality for both input and output drops significantly. Upon closer inspection it seems that the codec switches from A2DP to HDP whenever the mic is active. Why is this, how can I fix it (force aptX or A2DP all the time), and as a bonus is there a way I can use aptX?

Edits for context: I am using a BT headset that sounds quite fine when I'm just listening to music but when I try to use the mic, others have a hard time hearing me and I turn off my music because of how horrible it sounds.

Comment: You can't - A2DP does not support mic input

Comment: @mmmmmm I'm already doing something like this. It's unfortunate and inconvenient however, and is not good at all when my fans are firing. Furthermore, it does not answer the implied question: how can I use my BT headset for input and output while keeping the audio quality?

Comment: It does provide the current answer - You can't - it is the answer although unfortunately the one we want

Comment: Does aptX? The Bluetooth Explorer does not work in Big Sur to do this but I know it worked in prior versions is there a workaround?